Error while trying to download any VS Code extension: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR: Download: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
I recently got a used computer from my brother that he did not use at all, but was used by one of his friends who showed me that he only used it to browse the web. It's a Lenovo ThinkPad running Windows 10. I didn't format the computer but I did change the user/administrator name and password to mine own. I downloaded the most recent version of Visual Studio Code (x64) and started to install extensions, but come across the "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" every time I try to install it ("Error while installing {extension name} extension. Please check the log for more details."). That SSL protocol error is in the log.
I also get the XHR error (see: Visual Studio Code Error While Fetching Extensions XHR Failed) when trying to load the page for the extension in VS Code, but it eventually loads anyway. Here's the error I get when trying to install an extension ({user} replaces the actual user name):
[error] net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, : Download: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, 
    at J.L (c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:67909)
    at async J.I (c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:64411)
    at async J.installGalleryExtensions (c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:60369)
    at async J.installFromGallery (c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:104:59585)

I have no idea what's wrong. Thank you in advance for your help.
I also tried restarting the computer and VS Code, but it ultimately results back to that error. I have not tried downloading manually (which I don't really want to do).


update: it's only some extensions that don't work. For example, I was able to download CMake, CMake, and CMake Language Support extensions, but was not able to download, for example, .NET Install Tool, C#, C# Dev Kit.

